# Can't apply to_address of unique_ptr of array

Tags: c++

In this MCVE:

```
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> myChars = std::make_unique<char[]>(20); 

    const char* cs = to_address (myChars);
    
    return 0;
}
```

g++ can't handle applying `to_address` to `myChars` -- it complains that `unique_ptr<char[]>` has no member named `->`.  I'm using g++10, but `to_address` was supported since g++8. Am I misusing it, or is this supposed to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::to_address()` converts a pointer-like type (like a smart pointer) to a raw pointer.  By default, for a pointer-like type, `std::to_address()` uses the type's `operator->` to obtain the raw pointer being held by the type.  However, the array specialization of `unique_ptr` has no `operator->`, hence the error you are seeing.

`to_address()` also accepts a raw pointer and returns it as-is.  You can use the `unique_ptr::get()` method to get the raw pointer being held, eg:

```cpp
const char* cs = to_address(myChars.get());
```

In which case, using `to_address()` is redundant and can be omitted:

```cpp
const char* cs = myChars.get();
```

Otherwise, you can provide your own specialization of `to_address()` for `unique_ptr<T[]>`, eg:

```cpp
template< class T >
constexpr auto to_address(const std::unique_ptr<T[]> &p) noexcept
{
    return p.get();
}

...

auto myChars = std::make_unique<char[]>(20); 
const char* cs = to_address(myChars);
```

Or better, provide a specialization of `std::pointer_traits` for `unique_ptr<T[]>`, which `std::to_address()` can then use, eg:

```cpp
template<class T>
struct pointer_traits<std::unique_ptr<T[]>>
{
    using pointer = std::unique_ptr<T[]>;
    using element_type = pointer::element_type;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;

    static element_type* to_address(const pointer &p) noexcept
    {
        return p.get();
    }
};

...

auto myChars = std::make_unique<char[]>(20); 
const char* cs = std::to_address(myChars);
```